# JAVA - SSL Client - Key managers not used

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, alias, keystore

I implemented a custom key manager, in order to choose which alias use when i need a ssl handshake.
The problem is that none of the methods of my custom key manager gets called, although it's correctly instantiated.

**With a keystore containing just ONE alias, communication is fine and the code works, but the aim here is to have the possibility to change aliases during runtime.**

Here is the full code of my implementation. Any Help is appreciated.

```
package ssl;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedKeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;

public class AliasSelectorKeyManager extends X509ExtendedKeyManager {

    private X509KeyManager sourceKeyManager = null;
    private String alias;

    public AliasSelectorKeyManager(X509KeyManager keyManager, String alias) {
        this.sourceKeyManager = keyManager;
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseEngineClientAlias(String[] paramArrayOfString, Principal[] paramArrayOfPrincipal, SSLEngine paramSSLEngine) {

        return chooseClientAlias(paramArrayOfString, paramArrayOfPrincipal, null);
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        boolean aliasFound = false;

        //Get all aliases from the key manager. If any matches with the managed alias,
        //then return it.
        //If the alias has not been found, return null (and let the API to handle it, 
        //causing the handshake to fail).

        for (int i = 0; i < keyType.length && !aliasFound; i++) {
            String[] validAliases = sourceKeyManager.getClientAliases(keyType[i], issuers);
            if (validAliases != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < validAliases.length && !aliasFound; j++) {

                    if (validAliases[j].equals(alias)) {

                        aliasFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (aliasFound) {
            return alias;
        } else {

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

All this does is simply override each method calling the specific `sourceKeyManager` implementation. The customization comes into the two methods:

- **chooseEngineClientAlias**;
- **chooseClientAlias**

This is my SSL client main:

```
package ssl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class SSLClientV2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String keyStoreType = "PKCS12";
        String keyManagementAlgorithm = "SunX509";
        String keyStorePassword = "password";
        String keyStoreFileName = "C:/keystore.p12";

        String protocolVersion = "TLSv1.2";

        System.out.println("Key store File name.......: " + keyStoreFileName);
        System.out.println("Key store type............: " + keyStoreType);
        System.out.println("Key store Password........: " + keyStorePassword);
        System.out.println("SSL Protocol..............: " + protocolVersion);
        System.out.println("Key Management Algorithm..: " + keyManagementAlgorithm);

        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());

        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = null;
        SSLContext sslContext = null;

        try (FileInputStream keyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFileName)) {

            System.out.println("Loading keystore...");
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(keyStoreFile, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

            System.out.println("Keystore loaded successfully.");
        } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {

            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not load keystore.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());

        if (keyStore != null) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Initializing Key Manager Factory...");

                keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(keyManagementAlgorithm);
                keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

                System.out.println("Key Manager Factory initialized successfully.");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyStoreException e) {

                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not initialize Key Manager Factory.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());

        if (keyManagerFactory != null) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Initializing SSL Context...");

                KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
                TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] {

                        new X509TrustManager() {

                            @Override
                            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {

                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate, String paramString) throws CertificateException {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate, String paramString) throws CertificateException {

                            }
                        }
                };

                for (int i = 0; i < keyManagers.length; i++) {
                    if (keyManagers[i] instanceof X509KeyManager) {

                        keyManagers[i] = new AliasSelectorKeyManager((X509KeyManager) keyManagers[i], "my.custom.alias");
                        System.out.println("Custom Key Manager loaded (#" + (i + 1) + ", class: " + keyManagers[i].getClass().getName() + ")");
                    }
                }

                sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(protocolVersion);
                SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

                secureRandom.nextInt();
                sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, secureRandom);

                System.out.println("SSL Context initialized successfully.");
            } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not initialize SSL Context.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
        if (sslContext != null) {

            try (SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket("192.168.10.10", 1443)) {

                System.out.println("Communication initialized, starting handshake...");
                socket.startHandshake();

                System.out.println("Handshake completed successfully.");
                BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String m = null;

                System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());

                String content = "Hello World";
                System.out.println("Sending: " + content);

                w.write(content);
                w.flush();

                System.out.println("Message received: ");
                while ((m = r.readLine()) != null) {

                    System.out.println(m);
                }

                w.close();
                r.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please override also this method:
X509KeyManager::getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. how should I implement this method? Should it do the same stuff as chooseClientAlias?

Comment: Also, this method seems not to be automatically invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Has the `needClientAuth` flag been turned on the server side?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html#setNeedClientAuth(boolean)

The server asks the client’s authentication during the handshake only if the flag is turned on.